# php pdo oop show desired data only

Tags: php, pdo

I manage to edit a code I copied from a tutorial

```
public function viewItem(){

    self::conn();
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.guitar WHERE id=:id";
        $q = self::$db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(':id' => $this->id));
        $row = $q->rowCount();
        if ($row == 0)
        {
            echo 'no records found.';
        }
        else
        {
            $results = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,
            "Guitar",
            array('id', 'make', 'model', 'colour', 'price'));
        }
    }catch (Exception $e){
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $results;    
}
```

I fetched all data, according to Id, my problem is what if I want the color to show instead all.

Comment: What do you mean by "want the color to show instead all"?

Comment: He wants to get the value of the color field instead of printing all of the fields at return $results.

Comment: :) so sorry for not being clear. Sir Mattis is right.

Answer (score 1):

This will return the colors only:

```
public function viewItem(){

    self::conn();
    try {
        $retVal = array();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.guitar WHERE id=:id";
        $q = self::$db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(':id' => $this->id));
        $row = $q->rowCount();
        if ($row == 0)
        {
            echo 'no records found.';
        }
        else
        {
            $results = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,"Guitar",

            foreach($result as $row)
                $retVal[] = $row['colour'];
        }
    }catch (Exception $e){
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $retVal;    
}
```

Comment: I see light,but I want to show my fields from other document. This works for me but it shows all fields.  `code`$guitar = new Guitar($id,"", "", "", "");
$items = $guitar->viewItem();`code`
print_r($items);

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say. What do you wish to accomplish? Try to be a little more specific, what is "other document"? Edited the code to return all colors. Does this help?

Comment: I used require to call the class. Seems like this: `foreach($result as $row)
                $retVal[] = $row['colour'];`

Comment: this is how I call my getAll class `$guitars = Guitar::getAll();
 foreach ($guitars as $guitar) {
 $color = $guitar->getColour();
 $maker = $guitar->getMake();
 $id = $guitar->id();` It works fine, this is what I wanted to  do with my viewItem class.

Answer (score 0):

change these two line in your code

```
$sql = "SELECT `colour` FROM dbo.guitar WHERE id=:id";
```

and

```
array('colour')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is relatively simple:

```
public function viewItem(array $fields = array('id', 'make', 'model', 'colour', 'price'))
{
    self::conn();
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT ".implode(',',$fields)." FROM dbo.guitar WHERE id=:id";
        $q = self::$db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(':id' => $this->id));
        $row = $q->rowCount();
        if ($row == 0)
        {
            echo 'no records found.';
        }
        else
        {
            $results = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,
            "Guitar",$fields);
        }
    }catch (Exception $e){
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $results;    
}
```

This method accepts an array argument, or no arguments at all. Pass `array('colour')` and you'll only query for the `colour` data. Passing no arguments fetches all data, whereas `array('id', 'make', 'model')` fetches `id`, `make` and `model`.

This solution is, perhaps, a bit crude and could therefore do with some more work, but this should help you on your way.

Comment: this is how I call my getAll class `$guitars = Guitar::getAll(); foreach ($guitars as $guitar) { $color = $guitar->getColour(); $maker = $guitar->getMake(); $id = $guitar->id(); ` this is what I wanted to do with my viewItem class.